# Degree of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and let $f(x), g(x) \in F[x]$. Suppose $\langle f(x) \rangle = \langle g(x) \rangle$.

What is $\deg(f)$ and $\deg(g)$ and what is the connection between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Can I assume $f$ and $g$ are polynomials of degree $m$ and $n$ respectively?

Comment: I hope you accept my pedantry, I wanted to get the "deg" straight :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "can I assume that $f$ and $g$ are polynomials of degree $m$ and $n$ respectively" ? Are $f$ and $g$ not polynomials by hypothesis ? Then why could you not call $m$ the degree of $f$ and $n$ the degree of $g$ if you want to ?

In general, in a domain $R$, the fact that $\langle a\rangle = \langle b\rangle$ for $a,b\in R$ implies that $a$ and $b$ are related by a unit : you have $a=tb$ and $b=ta$ so $a=sta$ and $st=1$ (if $a=0$ it's even easier).

In this case, it means that $f$ and $g$ are associated : there is $\lambda\in F^*$ such that $f=\lambda g$, and in particular they have the same degree.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)\in <g(x)>$ implies $f(x)=u(x)g(x)$, $g(x)\in <f(x)>$ implies $g(x)=v(x)f(x)$. Thus $f(x)=u(x)v(x)f(x)$. Thus $u(x)v(x)=1$. This implies that $u(x),v(x)$ are constant.